# WPF/XAML ResourceDictionary with blank space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using af ResourceDictionary for translating

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <System:String x:Key="NumStartsTotal">Total: </System:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I access it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource NumStartsTotal}" />
```

I would like the output to be "Total: " (with the blank space), but it comes out "Total:" (without the blank space).

Is this intentional? and how can I change it?

Thanks! - Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `xml:space="preserve"` to your resource. This will, like it says, preserve the space.

```
<System:String xml:space="preserve" x:Key="NumStartsTotal">Total: </System:String>
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788720(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788746(v=vs.110).aspx).